# Почему программа считает неправильно?

Tags: c++, олимпиада, физика, вычислительный-эксперимент

> На идеально гладкой горизонтальной поверхности неподвижно стоит куб с массой m1. Неподалеку от куба возвышается стена, плоскость которой параллельна одной из боковых граней куба. С противоположной от стены стороны с некоторой скоростью скользит в направлении стены куб с массой m2 ,. Скорость перпендикулярна к стене и боковым граням обоих кубов Все удары абсолютно упругие. Понятно, что после столкновения первый куб начнет скользить в направлении стены, после чего отразится. и, вероятно, еще раз столкнется с другим. Вам нужно определить общее количество столкновений, которые состоятся в системе.
> Программа  читает с устройства стандартного ввода два целых числа m1 и m2 - массы кубов (1 ≤ m1 ≤ m2 ≤ 103). Программа выводит единственное целое число - количество ударов.

[Ссылка на решение](https://elementy.ru/problems/595/Odnomernyy_bilyard). Почему программа считает неправильно?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.14159265
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int m1, m2;
    int rez;
    cout << "Enter m1 і m2" << endl;
    cin >> m1 >> m2;
    if (m1 == m2) {
        rez = 3;
        cout << rez << endl;
    }
    else {
        double tan = sqrt(m1 / m2);
        rez = (PI / atan(sqrt(m1 / m2)));
        cout << rez << endl;
    }

    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Наверное делить надо приведя m1, m2 к действительным (double) числам. Иначе при m1 < m2 у вас всегда будет один ответ -- `PI / atan(0.0)`

Comment: но тогда что  с этим делать? Программа читает из файла два целых числа m1 и m2 - массы кубов (1 ≤ m1 ≤ m2 ≤ 103). Программа имеет выводить единое целое число - количество ударов

Comment: @avp ? Программа читает из файла два целых числа m1 и m2 - массы кубов (1 ≤ m1 ≤ m2 ≤ 103). Программа имеет выводить единое целое число - количество ударов

Comment: Так уже достало читать про эту задачу, что дайте URL проверяющей системы...

Comment: я через visual studio...

Comment: Я имею в виду, что это же какой-то олимпиадный сайт? Где надо проверять свое решение?

Comment: https://new.netoi.org.ua/index_ua.php?lng=ua&cid=2149 ну там не знаю можно ли проверить

Comment: формула tan отношения не имеет к rez

Comment: @Harry  
что-то получилось?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double m2, m;
    cin >> m >> m2;
    m = m2/m;

    int shock = 0;

    double v1 = 0, v2 = 1;

    for(;;)
    {
        double u1 = (v1*(1-m)+2*m*v2)/(1+m);
        double u2 = (2*v1-(1-m)*v2)/(1+m);
        shock++;
        if (u1 > 0) { u1 = -u1; shock++; }
        v1 = u1; v2 = u2;
        if (v2 <= 0 && v1 <= 0 && v2 <= v1) break;
    }
    cout << shock << endl;


}
```

Comment: Как вы это реализовали?

Comment: Так, как я писал - записал физические уравнения, решил, перевел в математическую форму. Просто сымитировал соударения!

Comment: @userofnothing, но и формула `printf("n = %d\n", (int)(M_PI / atan(sqrt(m1 / m2))));` из [Э.Л.Е.М.Е.Н.Т.Ы Одномерный бильярд](https://elementy.ru/problems/595/Odnomernyy_bilyard) так же работает (как я и написал в другом комментарии, используйте `double m1, m2;`)

Comment: @Harry Можете объяснить алгоритм?

Comment: Ну что, мне здесь решать уравнения упругого соударения?... Записываю сохранение импульса и сохранение энергии - m1*v1+m2*v2 = m1*u1 +m2*u2 и m1*v1^2/2+m2*v2^2/2 = m1*u1^2/2+m2*u2^2/2, решаю. Соударение со стенкой - просто меняется знак скорости. Соударения прекращаются, когда оба мяча летят от стенки, при этом второй летит не медленнее первого... Все.

Comment: @Harry для чего мы массу 
ищем?

Comment: Массу мы не ищем, она задается - *Программа читает с устройства стандартного ввода два целых числа m1 и m2 - массы кубов*

Comment: @Harry m = m2/m это для чего?

Comment: Чтобы не таскать две массы - в задаче достаточно знать их отношение. Поделите те уравнения, что я писал, на m1 - сами видите, что параметр единственный - m2/m1 - который я и обозначил через m.

Comment: @Harry нужно ли еще писать условие 1 ≤ m1 ≤ m2 ≤ 103?

Comment: Считать будет и при других соотношениях. Я не проверял. Хотите - допшите...